# How to simulate running on Wall like The Flash in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please is it possible to make a Player with rigidbody or character controller run on wall just like **The Flash**. Please guide me on how to implement this.Here's a [link](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e0fb5ebbf9c823c3dd34169b9cbe503b) of what I'm talking about. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can run on buildings as you would run on ground. Set the buildings layer to ground and adjust gravity when on building.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the player to be vertical to the building, adjust the gravity parameter on your rigid body (make it lower so the added force won't be canceled by it) and just add the force (or set the velocity, whatever makes you happy)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you already know how to move the player around on the ground. All you need to do is create some form of detection for when they want to begin running on the wall (maybe the player presses a button, or walks up to the wall), at which point you will want to do 2 things: rotate the player to have their feet on the wall, and change gravity to be pulling the player into the wall.

If we assume the player is facing the wall when they go up on it, you can just rotate 90 degrees backwards. Changing gravity should be easy too. Once the player is fully rotated, do something like this

```
Vector3 newGravityVector = tranform.down.normalized
Physics.gravity = transform.down.normalized * 9.8    //9.8 is the default gravitaty value, feel free to use a different multiplier if you wish.
```

(this script should be attached to your player)